# What are Weiterleitungshinweis Backlinks in the Ubersuggest SEO tool?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-development, analytics, backlinks

Today I was checking my old backlinks and I saw my competitor making backlinks exactly where I have created it, so I tried to check his backlinks using the Ubersuggest tool (by Neil Patel) and I saw his top backlinks were from **Weiterleitungshinweis** I don't even know what that means and whenever I tried to open then it was a redirect link but with different Top-Level Domain.

Below you can see that all the links backlinks are the same just different TLD, How it is happening and how I can create backlinks like this?

[image]

Comment: "Weiterleitungshinweis" - Google translates to "forwarding service" and all these links appear to be from Google search itself - not really what I would call a "backlink"?

Comment: So why it is showing as a High Authority backlink in the Ubersuggest tool?